# Running NServiceBus on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, nservicebus, esb

So I have seen a number of references and links from a year +/- ago asking about support for [NServiceBus on Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403838/using-nservicebus-in-an-amazon-ec2-hosted-application).  Wondering if anyone out there has attempted to do anything with this recently?

I have seen the following articles/posts but fear the information and related links are dated.

[A Less Than Positive Experience w/NServiceBus on Amazon EC2](http://meisinger2.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/head-in-the-clouds/)
[The right idea, any movement on this?](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/258)
[Azure Love, but no Amazon?](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/13085)

I see a lot of chatter on the NServiceBus forums about the "next version" having a big focus on support for the cloud (at the time the current version was 2.5).  I have a scenario where I would like to run NServiceBus w/MSMQ or RabbitMQ on a cluster of Amazon EC2 instances but it concerns me that there is not more discussion around people actually using NServiceBus on Amazon.

Anyone doing it successfully or have reasons to avoid considering it?

[EDIT] - Does anyone know if using reserved instances gets around the issue with EC2 restarts described in the article above?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are different ways to successfully run NServiceBus on EC2. Picking which option to go with requires weighing the balance of cost, scalability, & operational overhead.

### MSMQ

NServiceBus runs fine on EC2 with MSMQ, but there are a few obstacles that need attention. The main issue is that the computer names / DNS names on EC2 instances change during each restart. This is an issue because the computer name is used when sending messages to endpoint as well when subscribing to messages. One simple option to overcome this overhead is to attach an elastic IP to the instance & use its DNS name. The benefit is that it's pretty easy to do this. The downside is that you're only given 5 Elastic IPs by default. You can ask for more & Amazon is usually pretty liberal with handing out extra Elastic IPs. You will also be limited in how you scale. For instance, you won't be able to simply plug into the elastic scaling features of AWS. You also have to deal with backups. I would put the queues on a separate EBS volume & take snapshots on an interval.

I'd pick this option if you want to use messaging, but you don't have really crazy SLA's, you don't need to scale up and down machines quickly, & you don't need to deal with high message volumes. This is the case with most projects.

### Amazon SQS

You could write a custom transport for SQS. The benefit of using NSB with SQS remote queues is that you get highly available queues, you don't have to manage them on your EC2 instances & you don't have to worry about backups. It's also easier to leverage elastic scaling with this approach. The downside is that each read costs $$$, so it may not be economically feasible to read at the same speeds as MSMQ or RabbitMQ - although this problem is mitigated by support for long polling and the ability to download many messages in a single call. Another downside is that it doesn't support distributed transactions with DTC. If you're using NServiceBus 5 or later, you could implement the Outbox pattern in your transport as described [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/no-dtc), to ensure your messages are still processed only once. Otherwise it's up to you to ensure that your endpoints and handlers have idempotency solutions in place. You can play around with speed vs cost by adjusting the polling intervals of each of your endpoints & perhaps even have a back-off strategy where you decrease your polling intervals if you haven't received messages in a while. You will also have to worry about the size of your messages, as SQS has a small size limitation (256 K). You don't hit this in most messages.

I'd pick this option if read / write speeds aren't an issue, but you don't want to worry about operationally supporting your queuing infrastructure.

### RabbitMQ

I haven't personally played with RabbitMQ on EC2, but a quick search came up with a few articles on how to get it up and running on an EC2 instance. There is a mature RabbitMQ transport available and it supports guaranteed once-only processing of messages as of NServiceBus version 5, as described in the link above. This would be cheaper to operate than SQS & I've heard that it's easier to cluster than MSMQ. Finally, like MSMQ, you would have to come up with a backup strategy (probably using snapshots).

### Mixed

Nobody says that you have to pick one queuing system. You could use SQS for endpoints that need high availability & you don't mind paying the $$$, then use MSMQ / RabbitMQ for the rest of your system.

Comment: there is a page on nservicebus documentation page that describes how to solve issue with server name changes: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/configuring-aws